JOOQ removing milliseconds precision for Instant field (MariaDB)
I have a problem with conversion of java.time.Instant and java.time.LocalDateTime to SQL Timestamp using JOOQ.
Currently I am populating field as:
setField(MODIFIED_AT_FIELD_NAME, Instant.now(), tableRecord);

During the debugging I can see that field's value has correct precision in milliseconds.
However, generated JOOQ createField looks like:
public final TableField<PolicyRecord, LocalDateTime> MODIFIED_DATE = createField(DSL.name("modified_date"), SQLDataType.LOCALDATETIME(0).nullable(false).defaultValue(DSL.field(DSL.raw("current_timestamp()"), SQLDataType.LOCALDATETIME)), this, "");

And inserted value in the database TIMESTAMP column does not have milliseconds precision.
Note that standard SQL command stores value with milliseconds precision, so my assumption is JOOQ is somehow rounding the value.
Is there a way to configure JOOQ to keep precision in format of TIMESTAMP(6)?

TIMESTAMP(3) has millisecond precision; TIMESTAMP(6) has microsecond precision.

There was a bug in this area, but it has been fixed a long time ago. What jOOQ version are you using?

I'm using the latest version 3.19.7
